# Azure app registration returns error code AADSTS70001

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have created a provisioning mechanism not unlike this here: 
[group provisioning mechanism](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/MVP-Blog-Provisioning-an-Office-365-group-with-an-approval-flow/ba-p/166415)

I have successfully implemented the whole workflow on my developer tenant. Now our productive environment, I always receive this error:

```js
[Error]Invoke - RestMethod: {
    "error": "unauthorized_client",
    "error_description": "AADSTS70001: Application 'ffffffff-...' is disabled.\r\nTrace ID: ffffffff-180f-4bc4-8087-867633c83e00\r\nCorrelation ID: ffffffff-2e5d-481d-adee-f068dbebaab1\r\nTimestamp: 2018-10-29 09:06:59Z",
    "error_codes": [70001],
    "timestamp": "2018-10-29 09:06:59Z",
    "trace_id": "ffffffff-180f-4bc4-8087-867633c83e00",
    "correlation_id": "ffffffff-2e5d-481d-adee-f068dbebaab1"
}
```

This is my code, that should do the authentication:

```bsh
function Initialize-Authorization {
    param
    (
        [string]
        $ResourceURL = 'https://graph.microsoft.com',

        [string]
        [parameter(Mandatory)]
        $TenantID,

        [string]
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        $ClientKey,

        [string]
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        $AppID
    )

    $Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantID/oauth2/token"
    Write-Output "auth: $Authority"
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web") | Out-Null
    $EncodedKey = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($ClientKey)

    $body = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$AppID&client_secret=$EncodedKey&resource=$ResourceUrl"
    Write-Output "body: $body"
    # Request a Token from the graph api
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post `              #`
        -Uri $Authority `                                   #`
        -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' `  #`
        -Body $body

    $script:APIHeader = @{'Authorization' = "Bearer $($result.access_token)" }
}
```

I already tried generating new keys but I'm stuck. How can the app registration be disabled?

Can someone guide me in the right direction with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears the *ServicePrincipal* object for your app, in your production tenant, has been disabled. The *ServicePrincipal* object is represented under "Enterprise apps" in the Azure portal.

In the production tenant, navigate to the Azure portal > Azure AD > Enterprise applications. Search for your app (if it doesn't show up initially, make sure you've selected "All Applications", under "Application Type"). Choose the app, and in the new blade, choose "Properties", on the left.

If "Enabled for users to sign in?" is set to "No", then the app is disabled in that tenant. Setting it to "Yes" will enable it.

[image: Enabled for users to sign-in?]

Apps don't generally get disabled automatically, so it will probably be a good idea for you to understand why this was disabled, and ensure everyone is clear on what the requirements are.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly the problem. Quite confusing that this setting is only visible under "Enterprise applications" and not under the app registration directly.